# Textarea bulk add data

Tags: mysql, angularjs, codeigniter-3

I'm starting my steps with AngularJS.

He builds a small application in conjunction with CodeIgniter 3.

I created CRUD and everything works fine.

However, I would like to add a textarea in which I will add a lot of information in the format:

1. link1.com
2. link2.com
3. link3.com

The data will go to the database and will be saved as unique records.

My AngularJS - code:

```
$scope.noteCreated = function( note ){
    $http({
      method: 'POST', url: 'api/admin/notes/create/', data: {'note' : note}}
      ).then(function (){
        $scope.success = true;

        $timeout( function(){
          $scope.success = false;
          $scope.note = {};

        }, 2000);

   },function (error){
      console.log('Error');
   });
}
```

My html Code:

```
<form ng-submit="noteCreated(note)">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label>Note</label>
                <div text-angular="text-angular" ng-model="note.noted" required></div> 

                <select ng-model="note.id_domain_rel" chosen="directiveOptions" ng-options="item.id as item.domain_name for item in domain track by item.id" required><option value=""></option>
                </select> 
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-if="!success">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-if="success" disabled>Saved</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Now I can add only 1 value in input, and I would like to add a lot of information in texarea and I want it to be added to the database as unique records, e.g.

1) link1.com
2) link2.com
3) link3.com

Comment: Don't do this - it will get messy. If you want to capture a variable number of inputs, then create the input boxes dynamically.

Comment: @Shadow What if I add 50 records a day? Make it time-consuming.

Comment: 50 records a day is nothing. But the number of records is irrelevant. It is quite easy to add controls on the fly with javascript.